# Pandas Dataframe: Fillna based on an existing values within another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am trying to fill a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Name': ['James Martin', 'James Martin', 'Jill Valentine',
                 'Ben Murphy', 'Ben Murphy'],
        'Email': [np.nan, 'jm@so.com', 'jv@so.com', np.nan, 'bm@so.com']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
             Name      Email
0    James Martin        NaN
1    James Martin  jm@so.com
2  Jill Valentine  jv@so.com
3      Ben Murphy        NaN
4      Ben Murphy  bm@so.com
```

I want to fillna in the *'Email'* column with an email but this email has to be an email that already exists in this column, so James Martin appears twice in this dataframe and I'd like to use the second entry that contains his email to fill the entry that doesn't contain his email.

Like this:

```
# Output
             Name      Email
0    James Martin  jm@so.com
1    James Martin  jm@so.com
2  Jill Valentine  jv@so.com
3      Ben Murphy  bm@so.com
4      Ben Murphy  bm@so.com
```

I've tried

`df['Email'] = pd.np.where((df['Name']==df['Name']), df['Email'], '0')`

But I've had no luck with any of these, anyone have any solutions. Thanks

(Apologies for the poor format, I really would like to know how to build a dataframe and see its output in my SO question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby_transform` to get expected result:

```
df['Email'] = df['Email'].fillna(df.groupby('Name')['Email'].transform('first'))
print(df)

# Output
             Name      Email
0    James Martin  jm@so.com
1    James Martin  jm@so.com
2  Jill Valentine  jv@so.com
3      Ben Murphy  bm@so.com
4      Ben Murphy  bm@so.com
```

Input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Name': ['James Martin', 'James Martin', 'Jill Valentine',
                 'Ben Murphy', 'Ben Murphy'],
        'Email': [np.nan, 'jm@so.com', 'jv@so.com', np.nan, 'bm@so.com']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
             Name      Email
0    James Martin        NaN
1    James Martin  jm@so.com
2  Jill Valentine  jv@so.com
3      Ben Murphy        NaN
4      Ben Murphy  bm@so.com
```